# Kafka remove unused consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have an application that uses Apache Kafka and creates a new consumer group on every startup. It takes fixed string and adds generated uuid to generate group id. (ex. my_consumer_group_123324234234, my_consumer_group_123324234235 ...). When I shut down the app old consumer groups stays unused until **offsets.retention.minutes** after kafka doesn't remove them.
I wonder if it is possible to remove unused consumer groups (filtered with name like 'my_consumer_group_*') by script

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be possible using the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` script included with Kafka.

You could create a script that periodically lists the existing consumer groups

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka-servers-addrs> --list
```

Then describes each one of them

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka-servers-addrs> --describe --group <consumer-group>
```

One option to detect if they are unused is to parse the output to see if it returns:

> Consumer group '<consumer-group>' has no active members.

Note that relying on the message could be a bit brittle, since the message could change across Kafka versions, so I'd look for some other more robust approach (e.g. status code that the script returns (if any), initialize your own consumer...)

And then deletes the ones that are unused:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka-server-addrs> --delete --group <consumer-group1> --group <consumer-group2>
```